# how to enable ploting for zeppelin in Azure

Tags: scala, apache-zeppelin, helium

The Zeppelin installation in HDInsight clusters on Azure does not have any package  in Helium to be enabled. How should I add and enable them to be able to draw charts in scala notebooks?

Answer (score 1):

helium online registry works for 0.8.0-SNAPSHOT But I guess Azure provided Zeppelin is 0.7.x.

So you have 2+ options.

1. Use interpreter specific charts: [python-bokeh](https://www.zepl.com/viewer/notebooks/bm90ZTovL3pqZmZkdS90ZXN0L2VhMGI0ODQ0MzNhYjQxNjZhODg5MjI1ZjAxZWVjMjdiL25vdGUuanNvbg), [spark-highcharts](https://github.com/knockdata/spark-highcharts)
2. Install helium manually: https://github.com/1ambda/zeppelin-highcharts-bubble/issues/1#issuecomment-284950453